# Parsing strings for {0}

Tags: .net, regex

If I have a string like the following :

"part one {0} another {1} and finally {2}"

how can I parse it so as to extract the "{0}", "{1}" and "{2}" components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{[0-9]+\}");
var matches = regex.Matches("part one {0} another {1} and finally {2}");
// matches contains "{0}", "{1}", {2}
```

Remove the `"+"` if your placeholders are always single-digit.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx can be slow. If you need higher performance (because maybe you are parsing many strings of with this format) you can usually do better parsing it manually. This will work as long as you have good markers. For example if the word 'another' or 'and finally' appear in the strings you are trying to parse you may have issues. Otherwise, you can easily split this string up using combinations of 'IndexOf' and 'Substring'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's dirty but will work (provided you know how many values you to remove) and whoever reads your code will be able to read it.

```
String newString = String.Format(myString, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty);
```

or you can use an array of string empty rather than using `String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty`...

Comment: Besides the number of `{d}` parameters you've mentioned, another problem is that the string might contain other `{` and `}` characters, which will cause `String.Format` to throw an exception. Besides, I'm not at all sure the OP want them removed - that takes some interpretation.

Comment: The way I read the question was that someone had been given a string "part one {0} another {1} and finally {2}" and told to make it different values based on some parameters rather than just remove them. The question overall is quite vague, does the OP want to remove them or replace them with something else or something completely different entirely...